# Optimal solution for interview question

Tags: sql

Recently in a job interview, I was given the following problem.

Say I have the following table

```
widget_Name        |     widget_Costs      | In_Stock
---------------------------------------------------------
a                   |         15.00          |    1
b                   |         30.00          |    1
c                   |         20.00          |    1
d                   |         25.00          |    1
```

where widget_name is holds the name of the widget, widget_costs is the price of a widget, and in stock is a constant of 1.

Now for my business insurance I have a certain deductible. I am looking to find a sql statement that will tell me every widget and it's price exceeds the deductible. So if my dedudctible is $50.00 the above would just return

```
widget_Name        |     widget_Costs      | In_Stock
---------------------------------------------------------
a                   |         15.00          |    1
d                   |         25.00          |    1
```

Since widgets b and c where used to meet the deductible

The closest I could get is the following

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
     SELECT 
          widget_name, 
          widget_price
     FROM interview.tbl_widgets
     minus
     SELECT widget_name,widget_price
     FROM (
          SELECT 
               widget_name,
               widget_price, 
               50 - sum(widget_price) over (ORDER BY widget_price  ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_total
          FROM interview.tbl_widgets 
     ) 
     where  running_total >= 0
)
;
```

Which gives me

```
widget_Name        |     widget_Costs      | In_Stock
---------------------------------------------------------
c                   |         20.00          |    1
d                   |         25.00          |    1
```

because it uses a and b to meet the majority of the deductible

I was hoping someone might be able to show me the correct answer

EDIT: I understood the interview question to be asking this. Given a table of widgets and their prices and given a dollar amount, substract as many of the widgets you can up to the dollar amount and return those widgets and their prices that remain

Comment: I do not see how your sample table data and your sample return are related.  A query for every widget that exceeds the deductible price would return an empty set based on your samples.  I may be misunderstanding the criteria, but if not the sample doesn't fit spec.

Comment: i dont think the question makes much sense.  what is the rule for meeting the deductible?

Comment: Your initial question looks straightforward enough, but your example looks like your looking for combinations that exceed your deductible, which looks like you're trying to solve subset-sum in sql, which seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: There's no logic to your request.  Why not list `a,b,c` since they also meet the deductible?  Is there a limit to the number of widgets returned?  Any logic in the order?

Comment: Your question is flawed. It looks to me like you're interested in any widgets which cannot be included in a set whose sum(cost) is below the deductible. In that case your result set is just any widget having cost > deductible.... unless there must be a combination of more than one... in which case it will be any widget having cost > deductible - min(cost)

Comment: Are you interested in the set of widgets not included in the largest (quantity) set of widgets whose combined cost is closest to but less-than-or-equal-to the deductible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [Bin Packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) these are really hard to solve especially with SQL.

If you search on SO for [Bin Packing + SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D%20bin%20packing), you'll find [how to find Sum(field) in condition ie “select * from table where sum(field) < 150”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016419/how-to-find-sumfield-in-condition-ie-select-from-table-where-sumfield-15) Which is basically the same problem except you want to add a NOT IN to it.

I couldn't get the accepted answer by brianegge to work but what he wrote about it in general was interesting

> ..the problem you
>   describe of wanting the selection of
>   users which would most closely fit
>   into a given size, is a bin packing
>   problem. This is an NP-Hard problem,
>   and won't be easily solved with ANSI
>   SQL. However, the above seems to
>   return the right result, but in fact
>   it simply starts with the smallest
>   item, and continues to add items until
>   the bin is full.
>
> A general, more effective bin packing
>   algorithm would is to start with the
>   largest item and continue to add
>   smaller ones as they fit. This
>   algorithm would select users 5 and 4.

So with this advice you could write a cursor to loop over the table to do just this (it just wouldn't be pretty).

Aaron Alton gives a nice link to a [series of articles](https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=bin+packing) that attempts to solve the Bin Packing problem with sql but basically concludes that its probably best to use a cursor to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll put an answer up, just in case it's easier than it looks, but if the idea is just to return any widget that costs more than the deductible then you'd do something like this:

```
Select
  Widget_Name, Widget_Cost, In_Stock
From
  Widgets
Where
  Widget_Cost > 50 -- SubSelect for variable deductibles?
```

For your sample data my query returns no rows.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I understand your question, but I'm not 100%. Here is what I'm assuming you mean:

Your deductible is say, $50. To meet the deductible you have you "use" two items. (Is this always two? How high can it go? Can it be just one? What if they don't total exactly $50, there is a lot of missing information). You then want to return the widgets that *aren't* being used towards deductible. I have the following.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    widget_name char(1),
    widget_cost money
    )

INSERT INTO #test (widget_name, widget_cost)
SELECT 'a', 15.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 30.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 20.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 25.00 


SELECT * FROM #test t1 
WHERE t1.widget_name NOT IN (
SELECT t1.widget_name FROM #test t1
CROSS JOIN #test t2
WHERE t1.widget_cost + t2.widget_cost = 50 AND t1.widget_name != t2.widget_name)
```

Which returns

```
widget_name widget_cost
----------- ---------------------
a           15.00
d           25.00
```

Comment: Note that I didn't bother creating the In_stock column as you said it makes no difference to the result.